# How to change the SQL query in APi Platform generated in Swagger UI

Tags: php, rest, symfony, swagger-ui, api-platform.com

We're using APi Platform with Symfony 5 to create a REST API for a legacy database. The tables in the database have field `created_at`, which is set to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Therefore we don't manage that in the application.

For illustration let's say a table would look like this:

- id
- name
- contents
- created_at

Now the client would send a JSON like this:

```
{
    "name": "Legacy database",
    "contents": "This comes in"
}
```

This works fine when the client makes a POST request with `curl` or in their client application.

However, when they are inspecting the REST API through the Swagger UI, the generated SQL query looks like this:

`INSERT INTO table (name, contents, created_at) VALUES ("Legacy database", "This comes in", null)`

This fails, because:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'created_at' cannot be
> null"

In the entity the property `createdAt` looks like this with the annotations:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 * @ORM\Version
 */
protected $createdAt;
```

Is there a possibilty to change the query generated in the Swagger UI?